# How do I get the value of a selected option in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code (an example that PHP generates for me)...

```
<select id="outsideBlue3">
<option id="bgImg" value="4f6e2288e3ddsa.zip">4f6e216857a0d.zip</option>
<option id="bgImg" value="4f6e2288e22dda.zip">4f6e2188a39a2.zip</option>
<option id="bgImg" value="4f6e2288e3dda.zip">access-denied.php.zip</option>
<option id="bgImg" value="4f80b747ab81c.jpg">UntitledDocument.jpg</option>
</select>
```

The string inside the option tags is the name of the file that was uploaded. The value is the name that the file is on the server.

I have tried to use `$("#outsideBlue3").val()` and I have tried `$("#outsideBlue3").attr("value")` but it returns nothing. The first one I tried works when I remove the value tags, but then I get the string inside the option tags. I want the value tag's contents.

Thanks!

Comment: `$("#outsideBlue3").val();` should work for you, here's a fiddle to prove it: http://jsfiddle.net/vyFra/1/. Can you please post the jQuery you are using.

Comment: It still returns nothing for me. I added that exact code to my site. Will it make a difference if it's in an external js file?

Comment: No. Without you providing more information, we cannot help you. `$(<select element>).val()` definitely works, so the error is somewhere in the code you don't show.

Comment: Check your console for errors. It sounds like there is some other line of code causing an error, and this is a by-product.

Comment: I fixed it. There was something wrong with my code. Thanks guys!

Comment: It's bad all `option` tags have the same `id`. Hardly this is what causing a problem, but you may used `outsideBlue3` several times too.

Comment: Then I suggest to delete this question (or vote to close) if the problem was not related with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
$('#outsideBlue3 option:selected').val()
```

Comment: `$("#outsideBlue3").val()` should already work fine, so if this does not work for the OP, yours won't neither. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: looks like OP's problem is something else

Answer (score 0):

```
//getSelectedOption
function getSelectedOptions(e) {
    var options = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < e.options.length; i++) {
        if (e.options[i].selected == true) {
            options[options.length] = e.options[i];
        }
    }
    return options;
}

//if your select tag is a single select one  [next line return option selected]
getSelectedOptions(document.getElementById('outsideBlue3'))[0] 

//if your select tag is a single select one  [next line return value selected]
getSelectedOptions(document.getElementById('outsideBlue3'))[0].value

//if your select tag is a single select one  [next line return text selected]
getSelectedOptions(document.getElementById('outsideBlue3'))[0].text
```

Comment: This works, but actually there is nothing wrong with `$("#outsideBlue3").val()`. The OP must have a problem somewhere else. No need to make it more complicated than it is.

Comment: There is no need for all that, the value of a single–select element is the value of the selected option, so `document.getElementById('outsideBlue3').value` will do where all the option elements have a value attribute.